# How to increase selected dot in UIPageControl. (iOS 12.4, not duplicate)

Tags: swift, xcode, uipageviewcontroller, uipagecontrol

**Please do not report this question. This question are not similar with another questions about UIPageController!!! Stop flag. Read carefully.**

I find a lot of other question about UIPageControl. But every question about ALL dots in UIPageController. I need to increase size only for 1 dot which is active. For example we got 4 screens, when I am on the 1st screen I want first dot 10px, other 3 dots 5px. When I scrolling to second screen -> 2nd dot will be 10px, but 1st,3rd and 4th should be 5px.

All questions on stack overflow and other resources about increase all dots. THis question about increasing only current dot, which active at this moment.

```
class PageControl: UIPageControl {

var pageCount: Int
init(pageCount: Int) {
    self.pageCount = pageCount
    super.init(frame: .zero)
    currentPage = 0
    numberOfPages = pageCount
    let image = Images.outlinedEllipse(size: CGSize(width: 1.0, height: 1.0), color: Colors.darkBlue)
    pageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.init(patternImage: image!)
    currentPageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.white

    subviews.forEach {
        $0.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 4, y: 4)
    }
}
required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}


public enum Images {
static func outlinedEllipse(size: CGSize, color: UIColor, lineWidth: CGFloat = 1.0) -> UIImage? {

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, 0.5)
    guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else {
        return nil
    }
    context.setStrokeColor(color.cgColor)
    context.setLineWidth(lineWidth)
    let rect = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: size).insetBy(dx: lineWidth * 1.5, dy: lineWidth * 1.5)
    context.addEllipse(in: rect)
    context.strokePath()
    let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return image
}
```

I've trying this code, but this is didn't work. Don't know why.

Please, can somebody help? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @ElTomato provide with code.

Comment: @ElTomato I asked for help, not for critic or etc. Is it stackoverflow or I made a mistake and place post on forum for moral help? doesn't matter my code or not. I said that I've tried code in question, and It didn't work. I've tried to find answers in many resources but it didn't help. So, please, say to me, what I did wrong, when I post this question? I trying to resolve this problem right now too, but if somebody know how to do it and be a little bit polite for newbies, may be they can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think changing the size of the default UIPageControl dots view is still a private API on iOS. What I suggest is to hide the current default dots indicator and implement a new one by yourself, which should not be a hard thing to achieve.

Here is my suggestion for dots control, which you can follow him and build your custom one, with active dot bigger size.

GitHub FlexiblePageControl:
https://github.com/shima11/FlexiblePageControl

One of the ways to implement this is to have one root view controller which have one container view holding UIPageViewController, and one UIView at the bottom which holds your custom dotsView.

Communication from RootViewController and UIPageViewController can be done through protocols or weak reference.

Comment: Hi Doci! THanks a lot for your answer! Your example with images on the scroll view(content), I've got content on the uicollection view. I move your code from method   scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) to  scrollViewWillEndDragging(). As I understand it the same. It calling func setContent. So, indicator change color, but didn't change size. I run your demo -- it works well. I will try to apply this code in new test project. Maybe I've got problem with.... honestly I don't know where.. It work on your demo well!

Comment: Okay, let's hope you will find a way to make it work, I think you will!

Comment: I understood what happening, it didn't work when we got  4 screens totally. trying to manipulate with func updateDotSize ()

Comment: man thanks a lot, I resolve this problem!

Comment: Happy to hear that mate, all the best. Feel free to ask anything related to iOS Developemnt. Caring is sharing! Cheers!